# The bootnode is not working properly

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, peers, bootnodes

I am running a private ethereum network using geth. I started the bootnode first following the documentation and ran 5 different nodes on the same machine with same genesis file on same network with the bootnode specified. Three of them managed to peer themself but two of them doesn't have any peer at all. After 1 hour the 4th node got a peer but the 5th one still has no peer. I assume given enough time all the peers will sync up. Why does the bootnode take so much time to sync peers in the nodes? Is there certain configurations to speed up the process. ps. i don't want to add the peers manually using admin.addPeer('enodeAddr').